# Redirect to Current Page after Login

Tags: redirect, login

In my wordpress page, I add Login- logout item to the main menu using the code (in functions.php) below :

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_login_logout_link', 10, 2);
function add_login_logout_link($items, $args) {
        ob_start();
        wp_loginout('index.php');
        $loginoutlink = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $items .= '<li>'. $loginoutlink .'</li>';
    return $items;
}
```

When login is performed using this button, It should redirect the current page where login is clicked. How can I do that?

I think `wp_loginout('index.php')` needs to change because after login and logout I redirect to home page. What should I write to go previous page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`wp_loginout`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_loginout) accepts two arguments, `$redirect` (string) and `$echo` (boolean). You can specify the URL of the page to redirect to after logging in or out with the `$redirect` parameter. In your current code, `$redirect` is 'index.php'.

You can get the full URL of the current page by using

```
( is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

yielding

```
wp_loginout( ( is_ssl() ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );
```

That should do the trick!

Comment: Engelen thanks for your answer.But that line of code you provide me gets this error :/ Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/u935918480/public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/functions.php

Comment: remove the single quote before the last $_SERVER statement

Comment: Sorry about that, I've corrected it in my answer! Thanks @leromt.